# Function to create an array of images

Tags: array, objective-c, image

I guess I made the mistake of creating `UIImage *image1` to `UIImage *image11`. Can an one advise me on how to improve it?

```
+(NSArray *)stampImages{
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abcd.png"];
        UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fron.png"];
        UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"amule.png"];
        UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dog2_trans.png"];
        UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dolphin.png"];  
        UIImage *image6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hit.png"];  
        UIImage *image7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abcd.png"];
        UIImage *image8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"qw.png"];
        UIImage *image9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rewq.png"];
        UIImage *image10 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rac.png"];
        UIImage *image11 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gs.png"];  
        UIImage *image12= [UIImage imageNamed:@"acb3.png"];   
        NSMutableArray *stampList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,image7,image8,image9,image10,image11,image12,nil];
        return stampList;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the list of files you want to add to the array, then you can fast enumerate through them:

```
NSArray *fileArray; //List of file name here
NSMutableArray *stampList = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *fileName in fileArray)
{
    [stampList addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
}
```